# Computer never connects to the internet automatically on startup?

Tags: windows-vista, router, internet, internet-connection

I have my Windows Vista laptop connected directly to the router via an ethernet cable, and every time I switch the computer on, the computer cannot connect to the internet. It comes up as limited or no connectivity, I am assuming because it has not been assigned an IP address by the router - not too sure if this is right.

The problem is usually fixed either by performing a repair through the networking control panel or removing and re-inserting the ethernet cable. It will also connect without doing any of these if the computer is left idle for about 20 minutes.

It will connect fine wirelessly without the need for any of this, however I would prefer to connect via the cable. Any ideas how I can fix this? I have replaced the ethernet cable and router already (identical model) but these haven't helped.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Im not an expert on these sort of problems, but do you have the correct drivers installed?

Comment: When left alone for those 20 minutes, does it finally connect and get a different internal IP address from the router than it had the session before?  If you assign a static IP address in the DHCP reservation table of your router, does this change the situation?  Are you turning it on from a cold boot, or is this from Sleep or Hibernate?  Does it repeat this behavior if you just tell the computer to restart?  Or does it do this pretty much only after you have left the computer off for a few hours?